# Python3 - Iterate over dictionary, find specific dynamic value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have below dict:

```py
wordPos = {}
words = [...] #Removed for simplicity

for i, word in enumerate(words):
     wordPos[i] = ({word[5]: word[4]})
```

Which ultimately becomes:

```py
>>> wordPos
{0: {1: 'Kontakt'},
 1: {2: 'email@domain.com'}, 
 2: {3: 'domain.com'}}
```

Now, I am trying to search in above dictionary and if the string/expression exists, it should return the "key" for the value.

So, for example:

```py
string = "@domain.com"

if string in wordPos.values():
   print("The string: {}, exists in the dictionary. The key for this is: {}".format(string, key))
```

However I am not sure how to search within a dictionary, and return the key (of the value).

Furthermore, I am a bit unsure if I need to use RegEx to do the actual matching?

## Edit

I can see that I need to be more specific in regards to what I am trying to do.

So basically, I am reading an entire file word by word and adding each word to a dictionary (as well as the line number of the specific word) - thus giving me the following structure:

```
lineNumber:word
```

eg. `1:'Kontakt'`

Now what I am trying to do with this information is to open another file and get the **first** word of that file (in my example, the first word is `@domain.com`).

With this first word, I want to check if it exists in my dictionary (first occurrence). If it does, I want to return the line number. So in my example, for the word `@domain.com`, the line number that should be returned would be `2`.

Comment: Why would you use a dictionary like this? The whole point is to be able to do the _reverse_ of the search you want to do.

Comment: Actually, even the reverse wouldn't work because you are looking for substrings. You might need to think more about exactly what searches you want to perform - as it stands, the dictionary isn't really helping here, you're going to have to constantly do scans over all of the data and search substrings on every single value

Comment: What would be a better option instead of a dictionary?

Comment: That depends on what exactly you will be searching. You could store the domain as a key, and have a sub-dict against that key for all entries that share that domain. There are too many possibilities unless you can give some idea of what needs to be searched

Comment: @roganjosh I have updated my original question to include a bit more context! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function like below. This will return the first matching line number.

```
import re

input_dict = {
    0: {1: 'Kontakt'},
    1: {2: 'email@domain.com'},
    2: {3: 'domain.com'}
}

def search_word(regex):
    for k, v in input_dict.items():
        for _, v1 in v.items():
            if re.match(regex, v1):
                return k

print(search_word('domain.com')) # 2 (domain.com)
print(search_word('\w+@domain.com')) # 1 (email@domain.com)
```

Output:

```
2
1
```

Comment: This seems to work if the search word is exactly the same as in the dictionary. When I use it with `domain.com`, it returns none. Is it possible to search in the dictionary by using RegEx? Also, will the function return the stop after the first occurrence is found?

Comment: What type of regex are you expecting. I have edited the code to accept regex and match.

Comment: The RegEx should "simply" just match the input term. So for example, `if re.search(re.compile(r'{}'.format(word.lower())), v1.lower()):`

Comment: You can just pass input word or regex into the function and it should work. Check my latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to search a dictionary for a dynamic value, you need to iterate through the items, check to see if the values match, and return the key. There's no way to do it in a more pythonic way.

```
for key, value in wordPos.items():
    for inner_key, inner_value in value.items():
        if value == string:
            return key
```

If you already have an array of words, why don't you just use the `index` method?

```
if string in words:
   print(f"The string: {string}, exists. The key for this is: {words.index(string)}")
```

If the string doesn't exist, it raises a `ValueError`, so you could avoid the `if` via:

```
try:
   print(f"The string: {string}, exists. The key for this is: {words.index(string)}")
except ValueError as e:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is use python builtin `sqlite3` module and `FTS5` full-text index:

```
import sqlite3

in_memory = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = in_memory.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE "ftsentry" USING FTS5 (line_no UNINDEXED, data, tokenize="unicode61 tokenchars \'.\'")')

c.execute("INSERT INTO ftsentry VALUES (?, ?)", (1, 'Kontakt'))
c.execute("INSERT INTO ftsentry VALUES (?, ?)", (2, 'email@domain.com'))
c.execute("INSERT INTO ftsentry VALUES (?, ?)", (3, 'domain.com'))
c.execute("INSERT INTO ftsentry VALUES (?, ?)", (4, 'domain@sample.com'))

l = [*c.execute('SELECT line_no, data FROM ftsentry WHERE data MATCH ? ORDER BY line_no ASC LIMIT 1', ('"@domain.com"', ))]
print(l)

l = [*c.execute('SELECT line_no, data FROM ftsentry WHERE data MATCH ?', ('"kontakt"', ))]
print(l)
```

Prints:

```
[(2, 'email@domain.com')]
[(1, 'Kontakt')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the value of the value (which is rarely a good idea),

```py
string = "@domain.com"
for key, word in enumerate(d.values()):
    # We must here make the dict_values a list, and take the first index
    if string in list(word.values())[0]:  
        print("The string: {}, exists in the dictionary. The key for this is: {}".format(string, key))
```

Which is a terrible way of doing this. There are probably far better ways if you just can explain how the data you got looks like. :)